# Check to see what applications are using an Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, arcgis

We have an access database that resides on a server. We are using an ArcGIS Add-In to interface with it (both read/write). We want to be able to check to see if it currently being used by other person through ArcGIS.

Is there any way to find out what processes are using the database at a given time in C#? I have been searching around for this answer for quite a while, and can't find the right answer.

Comment: What wrong answers have you found?  Why were they wrong?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have only been able to find information on schema locks. Schema locks are not the problem at this point. All I need to know is where to find this information - if at accessible at all.

Comment: I doubt you can find out which processes are using the database (not without using Windows Instrumentation or something equally exotic), but you can find out *who,* which is more interesting anyway.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa155436(v=office.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By examining the lock file you can find who (which machine) is accessing the database.

This [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186304) describes this in detail, including a sample program.

Comment: The lock file *"who"* information is the Access security account user name, which is not the same as the Windows user.  And unless the db file is MDB format with ULS (user level security) applied, that Access security account name is always *"Admin"*.  The lock file does include the machine name from which each connection originates.  That may be more useful for his purpose.

Comment: @HansUp Thanks a bunch. That is what I was concerned about. Especially because we are using an application that accesses the database instead of a user directly accessing it - I assumed that information wouldn't be provided.

Comment: @HansUp  You are correct.  Machine information is what I was meaning when i said who.

Comment: @JuniperAsh Right. Without ULS, Access can't tell you *who* because it doesn't know.  OTOH, if your ArcGIS add-in allows you to write to the Access db, can you adapt your c# app to update a custom "activity table" in the Access db?

Comment: I would but the nature of the application is the fact that it can be sitting for quite a while. I think what you guys gave me is more than efficient thank you!